# Android Emulator - the error message 'Unfortunately browser stopped working'

Tags: android, browser, emulation

Whenever I click the browser icon in the android emulator; I get the error message 'Unfortunately, Browser stopped working'. I tried couple of AVDs; but no success.

[image: Unfortunately, Browser has stopped.]

What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Are you running something in the browser, or just opening it?

Comment: Do you get any error message on logcat.

Answer (score 25):

Edit the Android Virtual Device settings inside your AVD manager that you are using and try starting your emulator with the "Use Host GPU" option enabled, this will help to fix your error with the browser.

For downloading files with the browser make sure you also add enough size to your SD Card option. After editing both settings, start Android and goto: Settings -> Apps -> Browser. (If needed force to stop the browser) then goto permission and enable storage permission to be enabled. This will fix your error with the browser when downloading files.

Comment: Does not work for me, my problem is when I try watching some video (such as some Youtube video), the browser simply crashes (I'm using the Visual Studio Emulator for Android btw).

Comment: my problem was the external storage permission on Android 6.0 Thanks!

Comment: my problem was the permission for storage, Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Make sure that you have set the SD card to have some storage capacity - set it to 2GB and restart the emulator. The browser won't work without SD card storage, in my experience.

Also, be sure to get logcat so you can see any future error messages.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for a long time, I can't believe that was the solution. Thanks!

Comment: This also does not work for me, already set  SDCard size to 2GB and check the option Use Host GPU - not working at all (every time I try watching some video, it simply crashes). Btw I'm using Visual Studio Emulator for Android.

Comment: Enable external storage permission.

Comment: What leotesta says: enable external storage permission, by going to settings → apps → browser → permissions.

Answer (score 4):

go into settings, apps, select Browser, and then permissions. Then simply enable "Storage" and you should be good to go.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess the bookmark data got corrupted somehow. Just go into settings/apps and clear the browser data. You will lose your bookmarks though. At least the browser doesn't crash anymore.